# How much single-sign (static) charge is storable in a reasonable mass?

Tags: static-electricity

Let's take a high-voltage low-current AC source, and two devices capable of storing single-sign charges, at the ends of long wires.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpEgvy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This device, spinning in a uniform magnetic field (perpendicular to the lines) at frequency equal to the frequency of the source, will have a force acting on it, perpendicular to the lines of the magnetic field, and to the wire connecting.

it's an idea of a spacecraft propulsion in Earth's magnetic field.

This all rests upon the ability to store single-sign charges in the devices at the ends of the wire - this is the limiting factor of how much current can be driven through the wires in each cycle, and as result, the thrust of the propulsion. And I know about all current solutions of storing larger amounts of electric charge involve a gap between opposite-sign charges as small as possible. Still, even the old "rub the rod of a certain material to give it a charge" experiment stores -some- single-sign charge in the rod. So we can store some single-sign charge. The question now is, how much? What's the state of the art?

While size (volume) is something of a factor, especially for devices that can be unfolded it's not that bad. But mass is a significant factor, so multi-ton solutions are right out.

So, what is our state-of-the-art capability of temporarily storing single-sign charge in some *reasonable* (say, up to a few hundred kg?) device/material?

Comment: Look up "rail gun"

Comment: @ScottSeidman: Rail-gun has the comfort of storing a differential charge, not a single-sign charge.

Comment: That's what caps do.  Charges move around, they don't disappear.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: How much charge does a capacitor store if you leave one of its pins floating?

Comment: This question would probably be better answered on physics.se - electronics typically deals with current flowing in closed circuits...

Comment: @brahns: except I'm asking for a technical solution / device.

Comment: @SF. -- I'm no physicist, but I believe none.  Nature abhors non-electroneutrality.  Charges sort of get nudged around in  a cap, not added or removed.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: Definitely not none as the rod rubbed with cloth proves. Very, very small, yes. The question is how small, and how to maximize it (regardless of how small it will remain). Of course the fact it was a *capacitor* connected is completely moot. You could connect a dead lizard and the result would probably be better. The complex internal structure of the capacitor doesn't help the least bit here as the charge will concentrate on the surface anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The best I know is the tecnique used in supercaps: you let a thin layer of oxide grow between two metals.

As the capacity is reverse-proportional to the distance of the two metals, this gives you a great value for the charge over voltage ratio... too bad this reduces the maximum voltage sustainable for the supercap.

On the other side we have Van der Graaf machines, that can store hundreds of kilovolts in the metallic end, but have a very low capacitance (so very low charge).

That said you should give us some more information about your design to be able to understand what are your requirements: the currents you need in the wires, how that currents flow out of the capacitors, etc.

Comment: Oh, but the problem here is that these can't be just capacitors. As you wrote, "reverse-proportional to the distance" - and here we're talking about distance probably measured in hundreds of meters. For all practical purposes this is an open circuit! Keyword: **single-sign**. The amounts of current we can push, and charge we can store will be probably minuscule as there's no opposite charge there to create a differential.

Comment: as for other requirements: maximizing current, or more precisely maximizing charge moved through these wires in one half-period. We won't get anywhere far with it, but I wonder just how far (or how not far) we can get. Whatever voltage and other parameters it takes, *within reason*, so - well, no gigawatt solutions. Also - the ends of the capacitors are left floating in the picture for a reason, but in reality that will be probably devices considerably different than common capacitors.

Comment: So you just have a giant Van der Graaf machine... Imagine you have two metallic balls at the ends of your wires. You will have about 3kV/mm of dielectric rigidity between the two balls and with respect to the earth. You can evaluate the electric field easily with Coulomb's law to find what is the maximum charge in relation to the wires length.

Comment: Is "two metallic balls" really the best we can do? "With respect to the Earth" is not a problem (~200km?).  Dielectric strength of at least 20kV/mm (vacuum) and the isolation distance could be of order of meters. But I don't really see how I can apply Coulomb's law here... F=k_e |q1 q2| / r^2 - What would F be here for?

Comment: The problem is not the storage... it is the dielectric and you can do whatever you want, if you fill the space between the two balls. You can use ceramic insulators to increase the effective distance between the two balls but the order of magnitude of the charge amount will be the same of the case without insulators. As for the force, imagine an electron travelling from one charge to the other, the work of the field on it will be the integral of the force and equals $e \Delta V$. Substitute $\Delta V$ with the dielectric strength multiplied by the distance and you're done.

Comment: So you're saying the layout doesn't matter much - what matters is dielectric strength of whatever is used as the generator (picking the charge from one side and moving it to the other)? - it will be the "closest approach" point between the two. Also, probably for the current to travel the whole length of the wire, instead of just the charge congregating right next to the two poles of the generator, I'd probably need two generators at the two ends, working in sync - one moving charges from one "capacitor" onto the wire, the other - from the wire onto the other capacitor.

Comment: Well, you can't just have two generators, as there's no way to genearate a charge (without the generation of an opposite charge). Probably the wires will have to be of insulating material and you will need a mechanical way to transfer the positive and negative charge you generated in the voltage source (just like the belt in the Van der Graaf machine).

Comment: You can stage/stack the charge. If you want to move the electrons from one end of a long wire to the other, instead of just across the generator (leaving most of the wire inert), you need to split it into 3 segments: `c-g-------g-c`- first discharge (short) one end, then pump the charge into the opposite end. For reversing the polarity, discharge the other end, pump the electrons into the first one.